# Sum all records that have X value in another column and display value in a textbox

Tags: database, ms-access, controls, continuous-forms

for context I'm building a database for Wall Tiles that help a client know what ones to order. I have a query that pulls all the tiles the user selected on another form in a list via continuous forms. I need to add the Total of those tiles together, but show how many 8mm, 10mm, and 12mm tiles he needs to order in a textbox that's in the header of a form that the query is bound to.

*PickQuery* returns something like this:

| Code | Total | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B23432 | 4 | 8mm |
| B22343 | 3 | 8mm |
| B32423 | 2 | 12mm |

---

The intended outcome

| 8mm | 10mm | 12mm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 0 | 2 |

---

I tried this in the textboxes within the form header:

| 8mm | 10mm | 12mm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =Sum(IIf([Size]="8mm",[Total],0)) | =Sum(IIf([Size]="10mm",[Total],0)) | =Sum(IIf([Size]="12mm",[Total],0)) |

---

Also:

| 8mm | 10mm | 12mm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =Sum(IIf([PickQuery].[Size]="8mm",[PickQuery].[Total],0)) | =Sum(IIf([PickQuery].[Size]="10mm",[PickQuery].[Total],0)) | =Sum(IIf([PickQuery].[Size]="12mm",[Total],0)) |

---

What I'm actually getting is this:

| 8mm | 10mm | 12mm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #Error | #Error | #Error |

Any Ideas?

Comment: The first set of expressions work in my test of your data and form design.

Comment: I had reloaded the project and now I can see a #Error in the textboxes

Comment: The second set of expressions will generate #Error. Maybe edit question to show raw table data. Or might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Yeah I have used the first ones, That's what is producing the #error. Ill keep trying and Ill update if I find anything.

Comment: Give a try on `DSUM()` function like `=DSUM("[Total]","[PickQuery]","[Size]='8mm'")`

Comment: @Harun24hr, DSum would need more criteria to restrict results to specific client order. Should not need domain aggregate for this. Also, domain aggregates can slow performance.

Comment: @June7 Aggreged. As OP didn't get his desired result yet, thats why I just suggest him if it helps. For big dataset domain aggregate gives slow performance. For small dataset these are fine.

Comment: You all give valid points and I appreciate the help. I think I'll just write this up in VBA because I'm also having graphical issues and glitches I assume is because I'm using lots of calculated fields. I think my first solution is the correct one, I just cannot locate why the Error is happening, but I have to get this done by Friday so I wish I had more time to troubleshoot.